# How to use XGBoost to predict without labels?

Tags: r, prediction, boosting

I'm afraid I can't provide a reproducible example because I'm not sure what the problem is - I'm just hoping someone else can eyeball it or has encountered it before.

I am using XGboost to predict future outcomes. As a result, I'll use data up to and including July 2016 to predict August, September, etc. This means for my training data I provide labels to xgb.DMatrix

```
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix( 
    data = data.matrix( train[ , -1  ] ), 
    label = train[ , 1 ], 
    missing = NA )
```

This is all well and good. But I (obviously) have no labels for my test data:

```
dtest <- xgb.DMatrix( 
   data = data.matrix( test ), 
   missing = NA )
```

If I use a validation set and provide labels for dtest, everything works great. If I move up the time window and no longer provide labels, suddenly the predictions are only NaN.

I've looked and looked, and all examples and questions I've seen use a validation set with labels provided, and none make predictions for unseen outcomes.

What is going wrong? Once again, I'm sorry I can't be more specific. I've been trying for hours to figure this out...I must be missing something simple, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: xgb is what's called a supervised learning algorithm. That means that it needs class labels to do training. To predict future outcomes, you'll need features for those outcomes. In general, when you have data arranged in time, you are in the field of time series analysis. There are many questions on this website about time series data and how to construct forecasts. Please consult our archives.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a fairly deep misunderstanding of what you're trying to do, so while this may solve your immediate problem, I urge you to read one or several tutorials on out of sample prediction. This question is not about xgboost, and it is not about labels -- it is about a basic statistical procedure, that it is imperative to understand before doing analysis.

In your example, you are using the same function twice -- in the second case, trying to FIT a NEW model to your testing data (without labels). However, labels or NOT, this is not what testing data is FOR.

When you are doing out of sample prediction: First, you fit a model based on your training data, and get parameter estimate $\hat{\theta}$ (your fitted model).
$$
Y_{train} \sim f(X_{train}; \theta)
$$
Then, using your fitted model, and your testing data, you PREDICT new labels -- in other words, what SHOULD the labels on your test data be, based on what your model says?
$$
\hat{Y}_{test} \leftarrow f(X_{test}; \hat{\theta}_{train})
$$
Last, you compare the actual testing labels with the predicted ones, to get your out of sample error. 
$$
\mathbb{E}[(\hat{Y}_{test} - Y_{train})^2]
$$

A very quick search of the xgboost documentation returns the `predict` function:

`## S4 method for signature 'xgb.Booster'
predict(object, newdata, missing = NULL,
outputmargin = FALSE, ntreelimit = NULL, predleaf = FALSE)`

Meaning, the call you really want is:

`y.test.hat <- predict(dtrain, test, missing=NA)`

I hope that sets you on the right track, but I also hope that the next time you spend hours stuck on something, you consider that it may not be a software problem.